# Python CSV file get next row in variable

Tags: python, csv, file

I have a CSV file (versions.csv)

```
name,ver
Ford,1.0
Audi,1.1
Toyota,1.2
GM,1.3
BMW,2.0
Honda,2.1
Lexus,3.0
```

My current version is `GM,1.3`
i want to use my current version and then find the next version in my CSV file. Next version should be `BMW,2.0`

I need directions.

Comment: To clarify, you want to select the first row in the dataframe where the `ver` column is larger than 1.3?

Comment: no, i want to extract the next value / row located after my current version, in this example it should extract BMW,2.0

Comment: Maybe show the code you're currently using so we can see where the problem is

Comment: Surely this question should be closed.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the csv file, search for the current version, take its index on the table, and then take the next version.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("versions.csv")
df.sort_values("ver", inplace=True)  # forces the data to be sorted
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  # reset the indexes of the sorted dataframe

idx = df[df.ver == 1.3].index

new_version = df.iloc[idx + 1]
```

Your answer should look like this:

|  | name | ver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | BMW | 2.0 |